# Cross join table row with generate_series

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Currently I have

```
SELECT x, plans.name
FROM plans
CROSS JOIN generate_series(timestamp '2021-01-01 06:00'
                     , timestamp '2021-01-07 22:00'
                     , interval  '1 hour') t(x)
```

Table definition

```
create table plans
(
    id       serial not null
        constraint plans_pk
            primary key,
    name     varchar  default 50,
    duration interval default '01:00:00'::interval
);
```

which gives me a cartesian product of the plans table and timestamp generated series.

I would like to introduce a specific duration for each plans row, so one row could have "1 hour", mean while the other have "30 minutes" and then generate each combination for every row. A CROSS JOIN here doesn't work, I tried:

```
SELECT x, plans.name
FROM plans
CROSS JOIN generate_series(timestamp '2021-01-01 06:00'
                     , timestamp '2021-01-07 22:00'
                     , interval  plans.duration) t(x)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/97a12/10

Comment: Using 13.2. It says it cannot resolve the plans.duration column.

Comment: Updated question with table definition!

Comment: A [mre] with data will jelp tp understand better what you are searching

Comment: Added sql fiddle!

Comment: Ah, I see.  I had fixed your query without realizing I had done it.  the `interval` prefix to the last argument to generate_series is used for input of string literals.  Since plans.duration is already an interval and is not a string literal, you don't need it, and can't have it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/97a12/13

Comment: That's it. Thanks. How can I mark this question as answered now that you solved only through comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```
SELECT x, plans.name
FROM plans
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
   generate_series(timestamp '2021-01-01 06:00',
                   timestamp '2021-01-07 22:00',
                   plans.duration::interval) t(x)
```

Comment: I kinda want a cross join, but I want each couple to use the duration specified by the plan, so if Plan A has 60 minutes, I want 06:00:00, 07:00:00 08:00:00, and Plan B has 30 minutes, I want 06:00:00 06:30:00 07:00:00 07:30:00 and so forth.

Comment: Ah, then it should be much simpler, see my modified answer.